# Store multiple values from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm calling from a database the information of posts in a topic. I am using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to do so. I've got the first post working, but I don't know how to access the replies. So I figured if I got the list of posts in that topic, I could do so.

Here is a sample of my code that I'm working on:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE topic_id='" . $topicinfo['id'] . "'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
  $postinfo = print_r($row);
}
```

`$topicinfo[]` is an array of info on the topic.

The problem with this code is that I would like to save the results in a variable, not just automatically printing it out.

Is this possible?

Comment: please note: the `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete and it is **strongly** recommended not to use them. The PHP manual recommends switching to either the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions, or the PDO library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is push all of the results you extract from the database into an array.

```
$posts = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ...");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $posts[] = $row;
}
```

Now the array `$posts` will contain all the results from the database. The syntax `[]` is simply shorthand for [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

---

> #### [Using older MySQL library](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136610/172936)
>
> I suggest you avoid using the dated mysql_* functions. Using them for new code is [highly
> discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query). More modern alternatives are available and better
> maintained. Instead, consider learning about
> [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), and that you use either
> [PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). When used strictly,
> they avoid the tedious and manual escaping part, which thus become heaps easier and (as a by-product)
> safer to use. Check out [this PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) for a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you, Lix. This seems to work. :) Uh, do you know any reason why I may have gotten 2 to 3 down votes? :/

Comment: @tra - I think maybe it is because this is quite a basic problem. What you were doing is actually printing the values instead of simply assigning a value to a variable. Don't let it get you down though - come back and ask questions if you need the help! Also make sure to give as much relevant information as you can!  Happy coding!

Comment: oh - the votes might also be becuase of the `mysql_*` dilema. I recommend you take a look at some of the alternatives :)

Comment: Alright, I suppose it was a basic problem. The concept does sound ridiculously easy, just it wasn't working the way I was trying. Oh well, thanks! Oh, alright. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
    $postinfo[] = $row; 
}
```

That will add eveything to an array in `$postinfo`.

**HOWEVER**

You should think about switching from `mysql_*` to either `PDO` or `mysqli_*` - they both make it easy to write secure code.

Answer (score 0):

For storing multiple records from database you need to define an array variable and push those records into an array variable while fetching each record.

e.g

```
    $resultset=array(); 
    while($row=msyql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
    {
    array_push($resultset,$row); 
    }
```

you can access the complete sql query resultset through $resultset variable.